# Отображение Drag and Drop картинки без загрузки ее на сервер

Tags: html, jquery, css, ajax, drag-n-drop

Можно ли каким-то образом, используя drag and drop (например получив url перетаскиваемой картинки), не загружая картинку на сервер, отобразить ее в клиенте.

Сам файл мы получаем, например так: `var image = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;`
Но url этого файла получить нельзя, чтобы создать `<img crs="...">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const dnd = document.getElementById('dnd');

dnd.addEventListener('dragover', event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  dnd.dataset.over = true;
  event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
});

dnd.addEventListener('dragleave', event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  dnd.dataset.over = false;
})

dnd.addEventListener('drop', event => {

  event.preventDefault();
  
  dnd.dataset.over = false;

  const text = event.dataTransfer.getData("text");

  if (text) {
    let img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = text;
    document.body.appendChild(img);
  } else {

    const files = event.dataTransfer.files;

    [].map.call(files, file => {

      if (file.type.match(/^image/)) {

        let reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = file => {
          let img = document.createElement('img');
          img.src = file.target.result;
          document.body.appendChild(img);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(file);

      }

    })

  }

});
```

```css
#dnd {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px dashed black;
}

#dnd[data-over="true"] {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

img {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="dnd"></div>
```